# Get all products except that already had discount?

Tags: php, laravel

I have these two tables:

products table:

```
name - price - quantity - etc
```

discounts table:

```
type('percentage','numeric') - value - cancel - expired_at
```

Polymorphic relations: discountables table:

```
discount_id - discountable_id - discountable_type
```

there is `Many To Many (Polymorphic)` between them. So I need to get all products except that already had discount + the products that had discount but it's over with `expired_at`

Product model:

```
public function discounts()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Discount', 'discountable');
}
```

Discount Model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Product', 'discountable')->withTimestamps();
}
```

My wrong shut!:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::with('discounts');

    return view('cp.discounts.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [doesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) method,

The follow query will retrieve all products that don't have any discounts.

```php
Product::doesntHave('discounts')->get();
```

And if you want to get the products except it's over with `expired_at` + don't have any discounts, you can use `whereDoesntHave` to add condition in closure:

```php
Product::whereDoesntHave('discounts', function($query) {
    $query->where('expired_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
})->get();
```

Comment: Sir, I have a wired question! how can I find things that I need from Documentation?

Comment: @Jamal like this problem, its about relationship, so you need to find the relationship part.

Comment: Sir, I updated my question! can you take a look at it  again!

Comment: @Jamal updated. You can use `whereDoesntHave` to add condition.

Comment: It brings the whole products!

Comment: @Jamal is your expired_at's type is datetime?

Comment: it's (Date) I mean  the type in database. like this:  2020-02-13

Comment: And yeah in Discount model it's datetime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207516/discussion-between-tsaikoga-and-jamal).